# Nuxt store getter not working, ID given to payload is not an Integer + Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, store, getter

I am trying to make a product detail page. The detail page is named _id.
When opened the id is replaced with the product id. On opening the page the state is set with data fetched from an api.

After that i am trying to use a computed property that refers to a getter named getProduct() with an id (`this.$route.params.id`) in the payload.

This is how my _id.vue looks like:

```js
methods: {
  ...mapActions("products", ["fetchProducts",]),
  ...mapGetters("products", ["getProduct",]),
},
async mounted() {
  this.fetchProducts()
},
computed: {
  product() {
    return this.getProduct(this.$route.params.id)
  }
}
```

This is how my store file named products.js looks like:

```js
import axios from "axios"

export const state = () => ({
  producten: []
})

export const mutations = {
  setProducts(state, data) {
    state.producten = data
  }
}

export const getters = {
  getProduct(state, id) {
    console.log(id)
    return state.producten.filter(product => product.id = id)
  }
}

export const actions = {
  async fetchProducts({ commit }) {
    await axios.get('/api/products')
      .then(res => {
        var data = res.data
        commit('setProducts', data)
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
}
```

What works is creating the state, but when i try to use the getter something goes wrong.
As you can see i console.log() the id given to it. Which logs the following:
[image]

I also get the error: **client.js?06a0:103 Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.**

Which I'm not doing as far as I know?

**Note: **these errors get logged as much as the length of my state array is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Vuex documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html):

> Vuex allows us to define "getters" in the store. You can think of them as computed properties for stores. Like computed properties, a getter's result is cached based on its dependencies, and will only re-evaluate when some of its dependencies have changed.

Like `computed`, `getters` does not support having arguments.

But there is a way to have "method-style access" to a getter: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#property-style-access

> You can also pass arguments to getters by returning a function. This is particularly useful when you want to query an array in the store:

```js
getters: {
  // ...
  getTodoById: (state) => (id) => {
    return state.todos.find(todo => todo.id === id)
  }
}
```

```js
store.getters.getTodoById(2) // -> { id: 2, text: '...', done: false }
```

> Note that getters accessed via methods will run each time you call them, and the result is not cached.